# How to create multiple model instance (have one-to-many relationship) with an API call in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models `Product` and `Watch` like below

```
class Product(models.Model):
  
  id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
  # other fields
```

And the `Watch` model have the `product_id` foreign key connected with `Product` model

```
class Watch(models.Model):
  product_id = models.ForeignKey(
    Product,
    related_name='watches',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
  )
  # other fields
```

When I call an API to create a new `watch` with `product_id` in the request body. I want to check if the `product` with that `product_id` does exist or not. If not, I create a new `product` instance at the same time.

Currently, I'd overiding the `create() method` in serializer class like so

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    product_id = validated_data['product_id']
    is_product_exist = self.is_product_exist(product_id)

    if (is_product_exist):
      watch = Watch.objects.create(**watch_data)
    else:
      Product.objects.create(**product_data)
      watch = Watch.objects.create(**watch_data)
    return watch
```

But when calling API, I got the error

```
{"product_id":["Invalid pk \"57668290\" - object does not exist."]}
```

So how can I deal with this error? thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

you could use Django's get_or_create method which is a lot better.
it returns the object and a bool specifying if it was fetched or created

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    product_id = validated_data.pop('product_id',None)
    if product_id is None:
       # create an error to handle missing data here if you want to
       raise serializers.ValidationError("You have to specify product id") 
  
    product, created_bool = Product.objects.get_or_create(id=product_id)
    watch_data['product'] = product # not a mandotray row, assign the new product to the watch_data if you want to associate them
    watch = Watch.objects.create(**watch_data)
    return watch
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found another solution is that I call external API to get the data back and then create the product instance in ```to_interval_value() function```. So when ```watch``` instance is saved, it already has the product with that ID in the database.